# addEventListener not working and a few questions

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events, addeventlistener

I'm supposed to change the background-color of each div according to the key I press [RGBY]. Pressing R will get them Red, G for Green etc. It's not working right now and I can't figure out why.

Aside from the main problem I have some other questions as well :

**First**, should I use  document or window on the `.addEventListener` for this particular exercise ?

**Second**, inside the `document.addEventListener("keydown", switchColor)`

Should I do it like this or use `document.addEventListener("keydown", switchColor(e))` instead? I am confused about this one, because my `switchColor` function is built like this:  `const switchColor = e => {...}`

```js
    const divList = document.querySelectorAll("div");

    document.addEventListener("keydown", switchColor); // this or switchColor(e) ?
    //would 'window.addEventListener' be okay in here as well ??

    const switchColor = e => {
        let color = "n/a";
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 82: color = red; break; 
            case 89: color = yellow; break; 
            case 71: color = green; break; 
            case 66: color = blue; break; 
        }
        divList.forEach(value => {
            value.style.backgroundColor = color;
        });
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <p>Press the R (red), Y (yellow), G (green) or B (blue) key to change paragraph colors accordingly.</p>

    <h1>Paragraph 1</h1>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dignissim fringilla dapibus. Curabitur placerat efficitur
        molestie. Quisque quis consequat nibh. Aenean feugiat, eros eget aliquam vulputate, leo augue luctus lectus, non
        lobortis libero quam non sem. Aliquam sit amet tincidunt ex, mollis interdum massa.</div>

    <h1>Paragraph 2</h1>
    <div>Vivamus at justo blandit, ornare leo id, vehicula urna. Fusce sed felis eget magna viverra feugiat eget nec orci. Duis
        non massa nibh. Aenean vehicula velit a magna lobortis tempor ut quis felis. Proin vitae dui a eros facilisis fringilla
        ut ut ante.</div>

    <h1>Paragraph 3</h1>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sit amet pharetra massa. Nulla blandit erat nulla, et scelerisque
        libero varius ut. Praesent bibendum eu magna ullamcorper venenatis. Sed ut pellentesque leo. Sed ultrices sapien
        consequat odio posuere gravida.</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### window.addEventListener(...) VS document.addEventListener(...):

[`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window) and [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document) are different objects and have different events, so you should bind your events to one or the other depending on what you actually need to do.

However, there are some common ones, and there may be some differences between using one or the other, although sometimes both options can be used indistinctly without issues. For example:

- [`onabort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onabort): Called when the user aborts the loading of a resource, for example, pressing the `×` button on chrome (on the left of the navigation bar) when the page is still loading.

  I think there are no differences for this one.
- [`onblur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onblur): As this event does not bubble, you can only listen for it on a specific event.

  Therefore, if you listen for it on `window`, your event listener will be invoked when the window itself loses the focus (when the users switches to a different tab).

  If you listen for it on a specific element, let's say a `<input>` element, then it will be fired when that input loses its focus.

  Conceptually, at least for me, it doesn't make sense to even think of listening for in on the `document`. Also, if you try it out, you will see there's no way to make it fire, at least in the latest Chrome:

  ```
  document.onblur = () => console.log('Triggered from document.');
  ```
- [`onunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload): Called when the user leaves the page. This one is specific to `window`.
- [`ondrag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/ondrag): Called when the `drag` event occurs and specific to `document`.

Here you the complete list of [event handlers for `window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window#Event_handlers) and here the ones for [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document).

Going back to your code, you can listen for `keydown` on any of them, but I would say the most common thing is to use `document` unless you have a specific reason do use `window` instead, mainly that the event only exists in `window` (like `onunload`) or that there are differences on how they work in one and another and you really need to listen for it on `window` (like `onblur`).

One reason to do so is that propagated events will get to the `document` object before than to the `window` one, although the difference is negligible. For that same reason, in general, you should always try to listen to events as close to the elements generating them as possible for improved performance, although in some cases you will need [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to boost up performance in cases where you need to handle an event in many elements in a similar way and creating one listener per element would need too many resources.

Therefore, you should be using it `document.addEventListener('keydown', switchColor)`.

#### ...('keydown', switchColor) VS ...('keydown', switchColor(e)):

[`document.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) needs a reference to a `function` that it will invoke each time the right event occurs. Therefore, you need to put the function without the parenthesis, as otherwise you are not passing a reference to it, but whatever that function is returning when invoked instead, which would be `undefined` in your case.

Also, that code already smells even if you didn't notice the difference, as you don't have any `e` variable to pass it, so you will get a [`ReferenceError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError) if you try to do it like that.

#### Fixing your code:

The issue with your code is that when you do...

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', switchColor)
```

...the `switchColor` `function` has not been defined yet, so you will also get a `ReferenceError` here.

To fix it, just move that line after `const switchColor = e => { ... };`, like so:

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

const switchColor = e => {
    let color = 'transparent';

    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 82: color = 'red';     break; 
        case 89: color = 'yellow';  break; 
        case 71: color = 'green';   break; 
        case 66: color = 'blue';    break; 
    }

    divs.forEach(div => {
        div.style.backgroundColor = color;
    });
};

document.addEventListener('keydown', switchColor);
```

```html
<p>Press the R (red), Y (yellow), G (green) or B (blue) key to change paragraph colors accordingly.</p>

<h1>Paragraph 1</h1>

<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dignissim fringilla dapibus. Curabitur placerat efficitur molestie. Quisque quis consequat nibh. Aenean feugiat, eros eget aliquam vulputate, leo augue luctus lectus, non lobortis libero quam non sem. Aliquam sit amet tincidunt ex, mollis interdum massa.</div>

<h1>Paragraph 2</h1>

<div>Vivamus at justo blandit, ornare leo id, vehicula urna. Fusce sed felis eget magna viverra feugiat eget nec orci. Duis non massa nibh. Aenean vehicula velit a magna lobortis tempor ut quis felis. Proin vitae dui a eros facilisis fringilla ut ut ante.</div>

<h1>Paragraph 3</h1>

<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sit amet pharetra massa. Nulla blandit erat nulla, et scelerisque libero varius ut. Praesent bibendum eu magna ullamcorper venenatis. Sed ut pellentesque leo. Sed ultrices sapien consequat odio posuere gravida.</div>
```

Comment: @JDev I added some additional details, maybe you want to take a look at them.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly define `switchColor` before you use it. Then you need to use red, yellow, etc as strings so keep them in quotes. this seems to work:

```html
<body>
    <p>Press the R (red), Y (yellow), G (green) or B (blue) key to change paragraph colors accordingly.</p>

    <h1>Paragraph 1</h1>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dignissim fringilla dapibus. Curabitur placerat efficitur
        molestie. Quisque quis consequat nibh. Aenean feugiat, eros eget aliquam vulputate, leo augue luctus lectus, non
        lobortis libero quam non sem. Aliquam sit amet tincidunt ex, mollis interdum massa.</div>

    <h1>Paragraph 2</h1>
    <div>Vivamus at justo blandit, ornare leo id, vehicula urna. Fusce sed felis eget magna viverra feugiat eget nec orci. Duis
        non massa nibh. Aenean vehicula velit a magna lobortis tempor ut quis felis. Proin vitae dui a eros facilisis fringilla
        ut ut ante.</div>

    <h1>Paragraph 3</h1>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sit amet pharetra massa. Nulla blandit erat nulla, et scelerisque
        libero varius ut. Praesent bibendum eu magna ullamcorper venenatis. Sed ut pellentesque leo. Sed ultrices sapien
        consequat odio posuere gravida.</div>
</body>
<script>
    const divList = document.querySelectorAll("div");

    const switchColor = e => {
        let color = "n/a";
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 82: color = 'red'; break; 
            case 89: color = 'yellow'; break; 
            case 71: color = 'green'; break; 
            case 66: color = 'blue'; break; 
        }
        divList.forEach(value => {
            value.style.backgroundColor = color;
        });
    }

    document.addEventListener("keydown", switchColor); // this or switchColor(e) ?
    //would 'window.addEventListener' be okay in here as well ??
</script>
</html>
```